# Android Studio Emulator cannot run my app anymore

Tags: android, emulation

I am using Android Studio, I was learning some Android, everything was fine to the time that I realized I installed Android M (sdk 22 ) and Android 5.0.1 (api 21), I always run the emulator on api 21, everything worked correctly, and then I wanted to get some free Disk space, so I deleted the android M from the sdk, and therefore, the emulator couldnt anymore run my apps.It starts normally but nothing happens, any help guys ?

Comment: It's a little hard to understand from your question, but you have to have at least one API level installed. Check your Android SDK to verify that

Comment: It actually seems weird to me too, I have the android 5.0.1 (api 21) installed perfeclty , still, have the same problem